# High CPU With Multithreading In C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, cpu

```
    private static void aaa()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("123");
    }

    private static void Start2()
    {
        for (;;)
        {
            try
            {
                Program.t = new Thread(delegate()
                {
                    Program.aaa();
                });
                Program.t.Start();
                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                GC.Collect();
            }
            catch (Exception value)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(value);
            }
        }
    }
```

After experimenting with multi-threading, I developed that. The only problem is, I get 100% CPU levels and I cannot run it. I have done a mass amount of research on this and can't seem to find a solution, I've tried adding System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10); but that didn't work. Id appreciate all the help I can get.

Comment: You're creating threads inside an infinite loop. That means you're trying to create an infinite number of threads. 100% CPU shouldn't be a surprise.

Comment: What is this even meant to do? The example code is completely useless, so it is impossible to make suggestions on what to do. Also if you find yourself about to call a method that starts with GC, don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
private static void aaa()
{
    Console.WriteLine("123");
}

private static void Start2()
{
    try
    {
        Program.t = new Thread(delegate()
        {
            Program.aaa();
        });
        Program.t.Start();
        while(t.IsAlive)
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();
    }
    catch (Exception value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
}
```